# Python Property Change Listener Pattern

Tags: python

Anyone know of any easy way to track changes to a dictionary  object in python?   I am at a high level doing crud, so I have a couple methods that handle changing a dictionary, if the dictionary changes I want to call a function to basically do an Observer/Notify.

```
 class MyClass(object):
     def update(self, item):
        changed = False

        if(self.my_dict.has_key(item.id)):
           self.my_dict[item.id] = item
           changed = True

        if(changed):
          self.notify()
```

What I am trying to avoid is all of the tracking(setting the boolean) code.  Was hoping there was an easier way to track changes.  This is a simple case, but there could have been more complicated logic that would result in me having to set the changed flag.

Comment: `if item.id in self.my_dict { self.my_dict[item.id] = item; self.notify() }`? (excuse the braces and semicolons, but comments eat linebreaks)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can derive from the `dict` class and add a callback on any changes.  This requires to overwrite any methods that change the dictionary:

```
class NotifyDict(dict):
    __slots__ = ["callback"]
    def __init__(self, callback, *args, **kwargs):
        self.callback = callback
        dict.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    def _wrap(method):
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
            self.callback()
            return result
        return wrapper
    __delitem__ = _wrap(dict.__delitem__)
    __setitem__ = _wrap(dict.__setitem__)
    clear = _wrap(dict.clear)
    pop = _wrap(dict.pop)
    popitem = _wrap(dict.popitem)
    setdefault = _wrap(dict.setdefault)
    update =  _wrap(dict.update)
```

Comment: @Nix - Careful how, why? Can you please explain?

Comment: @VijayVaradan this will only work for first level property changes.  So if i have an `obj` and it has a `dict` and I modify the dictionary the change will not get picked up.  It will only pick up `obj.xyz`, that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Subclass `dict` and override `__setitem__`, making sure to call `dict.__setitem__` after your stuff to ensure the item actually gets saved.

```
class Notifier(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        print 'Something is being set!'
        dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)
```

Comment: How would you use `Notifier` then? I have an object that I want to know when a `self.__member` value changes? Is `Notifier` then encapsulated in that object? Can you expand on how this is used?