# Tkinter Add/Remove "windows" within current window

Tags: python, tkinter

Basically below is what I have right now. The problem is that each of these buttons opens a new window and I would prefer that in the top right I have the current function such as add course shown and then when I click the "add time" the add course would be removed and the add time be shown. Is there a way I could do this for each of the "editing" dict operations and also have an "up-to-date" table printed in the bottom right of this window? Thanks.

```
   class menu():
        def __init__(self, master):
            self.master = master
            self.table = {}
            self.createButtons()
#   creates buttons with alignment and their functions
    def createButtons(self):
        load = Button(self.master, text = "Load Table",
                      command = self.loadTable)
        load.grid(row =0, column =0, pady = 30)

        course = Button(self.master, text = "Add Course",
                        command = self.addCourse)
        course.grid(row =1, column =0, pady = 30)

        time = Button(self.master, text = "Add Time",
                      command = self.addTime)
        time.grid(row =2, column =0, pady = 30)

        reset = Button(self.master, text = "Reset Time",
                       command = self.resetTime)
        reset.grid(row =3, column =0, pady = 30)

        comment = Button(self.master, text = "Change Comment",
                         command = self.changeComment)
        comment.grid(row =4, column =0, pady = 30)

        view = Button(self.master, text = "View Table",
                      command = self.viewTable)
        view.grid(row =5, column =0, pady = 30)

def addCourse(self):
        #creates addCourse window and text boxes for input
        toplevel = Toplevel()
        toplevel.title('Add Course')
        Label (toplevel, text='Enter the course name').grid()
        courseBox = Entry(toplevel, width=10)
        courseBox.grid()
        label =Label (toplevel, text='Enter the hours per week spent on course')
        label.grid(padx=10,pady=10)
        weekHoursBox = Entry(toplevel, width=10)
        weekHoursBox.grid()

        #function to accept input from boxes into dict
        def callback():
            course = courseBox.get()
            weekHours = weekHoursBox.get()
            string = "0 "+ str(weekHours) + " "
            self.table[course] = string

        enterB = Button(toplevel, text='Enter Information', command = callback)
        enterB.grid(pady=10)
```

Comment: So where is the rest of your code ? I see only menu. Where is code that makes problem ? Where is code that opens "windows" but should add/remove elements (Frame, Entry, Label, Button) in current window ?

Comment: @furas I added one of my functions I call. The rest of them look very similar. I'm storing the data as a dict with : {course: "hoursSpent hoursAssigned Comments"}. It probably isn't the most efficient method, but I'm satisfied with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example - I hope it is what you expected.

[image]
[image]

```
from Tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master

        self.table = {}

        self.rightFrame = None # for first "grid_forget()"

        self.createButtons()

    #-----------------------------

    def run(self):
        self.master.mainloop()

    #-----------------------------

    #   creates buttons with alignment and their functions
    def createButtons(self):
        self.menuFrame = Frame(self.master)
        self.menuFrame.grid(row=0, column=0)

        load = Button(self.menuFrame, text="Load Table", command=self.loadTable)
        load.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=30)

        course = Button(self.menuFrame, text="Add Course", command=self.addCourse)
        course.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=30)

        time = Button(self.menuFrame, text="Add Time", command=self.addTime)
        time.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=30)

        reset = Button(self.menuFrame, text="Reset Time", command=self.resetTime)
        reset.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=30)

        comment = Button(self.menuFrame, text="Change Comment", command=self.changeComment)
        comment.grid(row=4, column=0, pady=30)

        view = Button(self.menuFrame, text="View Table", command=self.viewTable)
        view.grid(row=5, column=0, pady=30)

    #-----------------------------

    def loadTable(self):
        # remove previous content
        if self.rightFrame:
            self.rightFrame.grid_forget()

        # create new content
        self.rightFrame = Frame(self.master)
        self.rightFrame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N)

        title = Label(self.rightFrame, text='load Table')
        title.grid(row=0, column=0)

    #-----------------------------

    def addCourse(self):
        # remove previous content
        if self.rightFrame:
            self.rightFrame.grid_forget()

        # create new content
        self.rightFrame = Frame(self.master)
        self.rightFrame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N)

        #creates addCourse window and text boxes for input
        title = Label(self.rightFrame, text='Enter the course name')
        title.grid(row=0, column=0)

        courseBox = Entry(self.rightFrame, width=10)
        courseBox.grid(row=1, column=0)

        label = Label (self.rightFrame, text='Enter the hours per week spent on course')
        label.grid(row=2, column=0)

        weekHoursBox = Entry(self.rightFrame, width=10)
        weekHoursBox.grid(row=3, column=0)

        #function to accept input from boxes into dict
        def callback():
            course = courseBox.get()
            weekHours = weekHoursBox.get()
            string = "0 "+ str(weekHours) + " "
            self.table[course] = string

        enterB = Button(self.rightFrame, text='Enter Information', command=callback)
        enterB.grid(row=4, column=0)

    #-----------------------------

    def addTime(self):
        # remove previous content
        if self.rightFrame:
            self.rightFrame.grid_forget()

        # create new content
        self.rightFrame = Frame(self.master)
        self.rightFrame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N)

        title = Label(self.rightFrame, text='Add Time')
        title.grid(row=0, column=0)

    #-----------------------------

    def resetTime(self):
        # remove previous content
        if self.rightFrame:
            self.rightFrame.grid_forget()

        # create new content
        self.rightFrame = Frame(self.master)
        self.rightFrame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N)

        title = Label(self.rightFrame, text='Reset Time')
        title.grid(row=0, column=0)

    #-----------------------------

    def changeComment(self):
        # remove previous content
        if self.rightFrame:
            self.rightFrame.grid_forget()

        # create new content
        self.rightFrame = Frame(self.master)
        self.rightFrame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N)

        title = Label(self.rightFrame, text='Change Comment')
        title.grid(row=0, column=0)

    #-----------------------------

    def viewTable(self):
        # remove previous content
        if self.rightFrame:
            self.rightFrame.grid_forget()

        # create new content
        self.rightFrame = Frame(self.master)
        self.rightFrame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N)

        title = Label(self.rightFrame, text='View Table')
        title.grid(row=0, column=0)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

Application(Tk()).run()
```

Comment: Sorry I've been a bit busy. I'll give this a look in a few minutes and see how it works for me. Thanks for taking the time to help me :)

Comment: I just have one more question about this. Is there a way to get my formatted table to "self-update" when I say add a course to my dict so that it prints in the table in the UI? For example, I basically have what you gave me in the top right for the "tasks" but I want a table in the bottom right and have the same basic formatting, but I need a way for it to update itself. Thanks!

Comment: You have to create `updateTable()` function which update table and call it always after you change something in dict. Or use function `addToDict()` which add to dict and call `updateTable()`. Or you could use timer to call `updateTable()` every (for example) 2 second.

Comment: I got other idea. You can define class based on `dict` and override functions to add/remove elements which call `updateTable()` ([example of override add function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5186692/1832058)) but it can be more complicated than previous ideas.